# What is the size of a page entry in a page table given 32 bits physical address

Tags: operating-system, paging

Given that we have a `32-bit` physical address, where the frame offset equals to 13-bits and frame number field of the physical address is 19 bits. We are also given that we have 3 permission bits, 1 present/absence bit, and 1 modify bit, so we can see that 5 out of 13 bits in frame offset are out for the optional fields (3 permission bits, 1 prsent/absence bit, and 1 modify bit).

**Question**: I got the previous numbers after I solved part of the original question. But now I have problem calculating page table entry size. I am given that it's 5+19 = 24 bits, but I am not sure why.

Comment: The page table entry normally consists of the "frame number" (top 19 bits of the physical address) plus the 5 bits of metadata (permission, present, modified).  19+5 is 24 as you say.

Comment: @NateEldredge. Thank you! Instructors don't mention that when they first discuss paging! They just said `PTE  size = f.no + p.offset`. Since we have 13 bits for page offset, why the answer was not 19 bits + 13 bits please, which would make it equal to physical address (19 bits + 13 bits)?

Comment: The offset doesn't come from the page table entry.  The physical address is computed from the 19-bit frame number from the page table entry, concatenated with the 13-bit frame offset from the virtual address which we are trying to translate.  So the other 13 bits don't correspond to anything that needs to be stored in the page table entry.  Thus we need just a minimum of 24 bits for the page table entry.

Comment: @NateEldredge. Thank you. This is helpful. Wish if they discuss that in the class as this is confusing at first.

Comment: Now on real life systems it may be convenient to have the page table entry be 32 bits, so the other bits could be used for other features, or reserved, or made available for the operating system to use.  But if memory is at a premium on your hypothetical system, and they want the page tables as compact as possible, 24 bits would suffice.